# Iconography to summarize a table

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

I am building up a table summarizing several methodologies for a presentation. And I would like to place some coloring iconography to grasp some information at a glance.

Here is the problem definition. My problem has 3 different stages. Some methodologies address all of them, others only some parts and some others fuse some stages. To address the stages several characteristics can be used to address any of those stages.

Therefore I would like to build up a table where i classify the methodologies plus they description and add and extra column where i put such iconography as in the example.

[image]

I guess that the proper way to go is using `\tikzset`, having as many macros as colors combinations and use parameters to color it. But My problem comes when i want to fuse stages.

Is there any elegant solution to it?

Comment: What do you have so far? The circles/ellipses are very easily doable with TikZ/PGF even the ones with multiple colors (`path command` or just separate paths).

Answer (score 1):

I give the `\icon` macro that takes two mandatory arguments and one optional argument.  The mandatory arguments are a primary (left side) and secondary (right side) colors, the optional argument, if "e" means it is elliptical, rather than circular.  If `#3` is left as `{}`, it will be just filled with color `#2`.  If both `#2` and `#3` are left as `{}`, you will get an empty icon with a black border.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand\icon[3][c]{%
 \if e#1\def\cstretch{2}\else\def\cstretch{1}\fi%
 \kern-1pt%
 \hstretch{\cstretch}{%
  \raisebox{3pt}{\rotatebox{-45}{%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{%
      \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}%
        {\scalebox{.9}{\textcolor{white}{\CircleSolid}}}%
        {\textcolor{black}{\CircleSolid}}%
   }{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{%
      \mbox{\textcolor{#2}{\CircleSolid}}%
    }{%
      \stackengine{0pt}{\textcolor{#2}{\CircleSolid}}%
        {\textcolor{#3}{\HalfCircleRight}}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}%
    }%
   }%
  }}%
 }%
 \kern-.8pt%
}
\newcommand\X{\textsf{X}\,\,}
\parskip 2em
\begin{document}
x \icon[e]{blue}{black}\icon{red}{}\icon{}{}\icon{black}{yellow}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|lc}
      & STAGE &&\\
CLASS & 1\,~~2~~\,3 & CHARACTERISTICS & \\
\hline
& \icon{}{}\icon{black}{red}\icon{yellow}{} & 
  USES A, BBB, CCC, DDD; & [xx]\\
& ~~\X \icon[e]{green}{} & BBB & [xx]\\
& \icon[e]{green}{red}\icon{green}{blue} & BBB, CCC, EEE & [xx]\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]